# Hover on one element changes on another with css only

Tags: css

Hi its a very basic question i just want to know when hover on one element the style of other changes how can I achieve this ?

```
<form id="numerical" class="row">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Enter Number :</label>
    <input type="text" id="tel">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Result :</label>
    <input type="text" id="result">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="btn" class="row">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Like when i hover on `button` border-color of all the `input` changes.
I only want this with **css** no **js** or **jQuery**.

Comment: You'll need JavaScript in order to do that.

Comment: it's not possible in pure CSS, unless you place the button as the first-child of your form

Comment: With the solutions provided where button is placed before form fields in HTML code, you then need to visually move button below them. `display: table-caption` is a  bit hacky even for me but in IE10+ you can use [flexbox and order](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). There'll be an accessibility problem in half the browsers where tab order (keyboard users) is still button then fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**

```
<form id="numerical" class="row">
  <label for="btn" class="label"></label>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Enter Number :</label>
    <input type="text" id="tel">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Result :</label>
    <input type="text" id="result">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="btn" class="row">Submit</button>
</form>

<style>#numerical{
  position: relative;
}
.form-group {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#numerical .label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 32px;
  width:102px;
}
.label:hover ~ .form-group input {
  border: solid 2px red;
}
#btn{
    background:blue;
    color:#fff;
    height:30px;
    width:100px;
}   </style>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashubuddy/sq7v3xbp/)

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to do this but not with your current code.

Below is code of this working, the hover element will have to be before the elements you want to change. It works by going down and not up, so if this button is at the bottom you will not be able to see the same effect as the effect does not effect elements that are already rendered.

```css
button:hover ~ div input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form id="numerical" class="row">
  <button type="submit" id="btn" class="row">Submit</button>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Enter Number :</label>
    <input type="text" id="tel">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Result :</label>
    <input type="text" id="result">
  </div>
</form>
```

We can select other elements siblings by using the `~` selector.

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common
>   parent.

[More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

---

Here is the button at the bottom, as you can see it will not work.

```css
button:hover ~ div input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form id="numerical" class="row">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Enter Number :</label>
    <input type="text" id="tel">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Result :</label>
    <input type="text" id="result">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="btn" class="row">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

for a pure css solution you need to move the `<button>`-tag in front of the inputs you want to change, but then it'll work like this

```css
button:hover ~ .form-group input {
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="numerical" class="row">
    <button type="submit" id="btn" class="row">Submit</button>
    <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Enter Number :</label>
    <input type="text" id="tel">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Result :</label>
    <input type="text" id="result">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

that is possible only if the inputs after the button

```
<form id="numerical" class="row">
     <button type="submit" id="btn" class="row">Submit</button>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Enter Number :</label>
    <input type="text" id="tel">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Result :</label>
    <input type="text" id="result">
  </div>

</form>
```

and the css:

```
#btn:hover ~ .form-group input {
    background: #000;
}
```

after that you can use position absolute for the button
and this is demo
http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/6037/